# How to detect Apple User Agents in a Flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, user-agent

I'm making a cross-platform mobile app with **Flutter** targeting **iOS**, **Android** and **Web**. I want to show the **Cupertino** theme to users of **Apple** devices and the **Material (3)** theme to users of all **other** devices.

As for **iOS** and **Android** builds, I detect the OS using the [**Universal Platform library**](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_platform) and present the corresponding theme, no problem with that. However, as for the **Web** builds, I would like to **detect the OS using the User Agent string**.

By **"users of Apple devices"** I mean users who open my app on either **macOS**, **iOS** or **iPadOS** (or any other OS by Apple I missed, if possible), regardless of their browser. I would also include users of **other OSs** who specifically **changed** their **User Agent string** to make it look like they're using an **Apple device**, as I think it's safe to assume that they would prefer (or at least expect) to see the **Cupertino** theme; and I would exclude those who did the opposite, for the same reasons.

What would be the best way to detect such **"Apple device users"** in my **Flutter Web** app via **User Agent**? Right now I'm inclined to just look for /**Mac**/ in the **User Agent string**, but I'm afraid of getting many false positives. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this package from pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/web_browser_detect

This example is what you are looking for:

```
import 'package:web_browser_detect/web_browser_detect.dart';

void main() {
  final browser = Browser.detectFrom(userAgent: userAgent, vendor: vendor, appVersion: appVersion);

  print('${browser.browser} ${browser.version}');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but not really what I'm looking for. I want to detect the operating system, not the browser, and it seems like this library doesn't offer such feature yet.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting the User Agent during runtime, you can use [user_agent_analyzer](https://pub.dev/packages/user_agent_analyzer) package.

```dart
void main() async {
    app.get('/', (req, res) async {
        var ua = UserAgent(req.headers.value('user-agent'));

        if (ua.isChrome) {
            res.redirect('/upgrade-your-browser');
            return;
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

If you are using Sentry, you can detect the User Agent when a crash is thrown using the `event.request.headers` property:

```dart
FutureOr<SentryEvent?> beforeSend(SentryEvent event, {Hint? hint}) async {
  // Windows chrome user agent
  const String chromeWindowsAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36';

  debugPrint('event.request?.headers: ${event.request?.headers}');
  if (event.request?.headers['User-Agent']?.contains(chromeWindowsAgent) == true) {
    return null;
  }

  return event;
}
```

Comment: Almost there, but not quite. This library allows detection of MacOS user agents, but not iOS/iPadOS yet. Still huge thanks!